# How to parse a simple array with ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, api, docker, docker-registry, ng-admin

I have an API (http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog) returning a json structure as follows:

```
{
    "repositories": 
    [
        "start/imageA",
        "start/imageA"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to parse the result with ng-admin. My `admin.js` (CORS is solved on my webserver) looks as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('r2ui', ['ng-admin']);

myApp.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
        delete params._page;
        delete params._perPage;
        delete params._sortDir;
        delete params._sortField;
        return { params: params };
    });
}]);

myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
    var admin = nga.application('Registry v2 UI')
      .baseApiUrl('http://localhost:8081/v2/'); // main API endpoint
    var catalog = nga.entity('_catalog');
    catalog.listView().fields([
    nga.field('repositories', 'embedded_list')
        .targetEntity(nga.entity('repositories'))
        .targetFields([
            nga.field('.').isDetailLink(true),
            nga.field('.').label('Repository')
        ])
        .listActions(['edit'])
    ]);
    admin.addEntity(catalog);
    nga.configure(admin);
}]);
```

How can this be achieved?

**Update below**

Sorry I omitted the file `index.html` cause I thought it is to obvious to mention:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Registry v2 UI</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng-admin/build/ng-admin.min.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="r2ui">
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="node_modules/ng-admin/build/ng-admin.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The question is still the same. The array is not parsed correctly and I do not find in the documentation how this could be achieved with the given json.

Comment: The hint "CORS is solved on my webserver" was meant for this reason. The webserver acts as reverse proxy for the API.

Comment: Have the same problem, but I need also to add elements...

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, and I finally solved it by set the field type to "choices".
In your case, try to change:
`nga.field('repositories', 'embedded_list')`
to:
`nga.field('repositories', 'choices')`